NEW post type needed but with a taxonomy with a certain value with Advance Custom fields in wordpress
We are working on a real estate page and we need a new post type in WP that are only active listings that are ours. So far we have set up taxonomies from a previous dev and there is a property_ours and a status. Status is a list of strings: active, sold, under contract. These were made years ago by another Dev. The client would like a type that is property_ours and status (if it is active). I'm not sure how to look for the key value on status when making a new Post Type it just lets us add different taxonomies. Is there a way to create a taxonomy that is only status='Active' AND property_ours? I'm very unfamiliar with manipulating data w/in wordpress. Thanks

